# Expo React Native BarCodeScanner crashes when I open it the second time

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

`<BarCodeScanner onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject} />`

When I comment the onBarCodeScanned line the app runs, but of course it doesnt scan.

This happens only the second time I use the BarCodeScanner on another screen.

It works correctly the first time I use it in the App on an earlier screens.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this error an hour ago. I think the problem is that the camera (scanner) gets mounted the first time you open the first scan screen. Then you go to the second screen but the camera is still mounted, so when the second screen tries to mount it again, it crashes.

```
{!submit && <BarCodeScanner onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned} style={[barCodeStyles.scanner]} />}
```

I introduced that submit variable so when I finish the scan (or scans) on the first screen, I set it to true, so the barcodeScanner doesn't render anymore, and the camera gets unmounted. Now you can mount it again on any other screen. I would also unmount it the same way on the second screen even if you're not using it again on any other screen, because I dont know if having the camera mounted may affect the app's performance, so just in case.